# Smooth parametrizations of continuous curves

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Consider the curve $t\to (t,|t|)$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Even if it has a cusp in $(0,0)$ i can reparametrize it with a smooth function. Take for example
$$
t\mapsto \begin{cases}(\mathrm e^{-1/t},\mathrm e^{-1/t}) & t>0\\
(-\mathrm e^{1/t},\mathrm e^{1/t}), & t<0\\
(0,0) & t=0
\end{cases}
$$

My question is now if i can reparametrize every continuous curve in $\mathbb R^2$ by means of a smooth parametrization? It seems like the preceeding example hints at the possibility to do so for isolated discontinuities. But what about curves like the Weierstrass-function that are nowhere differentiable?

Comment: Each curve which is *piecewise* $C^r$ ($r>0$) may be reparametrized to a $C^r$-curve.  This is certainly not true for only continuos curves.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I mean for the 2nd statement.

Comment: For example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake